# several rows in a single variable sql

Tags: sql, variables, subquery

I have the following sql that returns several rows:

```
declare @blabla
select id from table where @blabla = blabla and blabla is blabla
```

it returns several ids like below:

[image]

Now later on my stored procedure. I need to get the result from that query. so I have another query like this:

```
select column from table where blabla IN (that 1st query)
```

So my solution was to put the 1st query above in a variable then execute it. So what I did was like this:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
set @query=
'
declare @blabla
select @body = id from table where @blabla = blabla and blabla is blabla
'

declare @result as nvarchar(max)
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@body varchar(max) output', @body = @result output


select column from table where blabla IN (@result)
```

But the @result above only returned one row.

[image]

which is the last row when my 1st query is executed.

I want my @result to contain the several ids, and not just the last. how can i do that? whats wrong with my script?

Any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you are assigning the variable @Body here:

```
select @body = id 
from table 
where @blabla = blabla and blabla is blabla
```

This will only give @body the value of the last ID encountered (depending on the order of the results).

In order to do what you are after you can use a table variable:

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE (ID INT);
INSERT @Result (ID)
SELECT  ID
FROM    Table
WHERE   @Blabla = blabla;


SELECT  column 
FROM    table 
WHERE   ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a temp table.

```
SELECT id INTO #TEMP FROM table WHERE ...
```

You can then go ahead and do

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```